# Is There a Scanner Function in Go That Separates on Length (or is Newline Agnostic)?

Tags: go

I have two types of files in go which can be represented by the following strings:

```
const nonewline := 'hello' # content but no newline
const newline := `hello\nworld' # content with newline
```

My goal is just to read all the content from both files (it's coming in via a stream, so I cannot use something built in like ReadAll, i'm using `stdioPipe`) and include newlines where they appear.

I'm using Scanner but it APPEARS that there's no way to tell if the line terminates with a newline, and if I use `Scanner.Text()` it auto-splits (making it impossible to tell if a line ends in a newline, or the line just terminated at the end of the file).

I've also looked at writing a custom Split function, but isn't that overkill? I just need to split on some fixed length (I assume the default buffer size - 4096), or whatever is left in the file, whichever is shorter.

I've also looking at `Scanner.Split(bufio.ScanBytes)` but is there a speed up by chunking the read?

Anyhow, this seems like something that should be really straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this loop to read a stream in fixed size chunks:

```
chunk := make([]byte, size) // Size is the chunk size.
for {
    n, err := io.ReadFull(stream, chunk)
    if n > 0 {
        // Do something with the chunk of data.
        process(chunk[:n])
    }
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! So avoid scanner entirely?

Comment: From what I understand of your requirements, a Scanner is not helpful.